# How to prevent overflowing border creating a horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: html, css, overflow, border

I'm using Bricks Builder to create a website. I created a CSS Grid. I populated the grid with blocks. The blocks have borders. I want the bottom border on one of the blocks to overflow to the right edge of the screen without creating a horizontal scroll bar.

This is the custom CSS I used:

```css
%root% {
    position: relative;
    border-top: 25px solid #101820;
    border-right: 25px solid #101820;
}
    
%root%:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    border-bottom: 25px solid #101820;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Using this same structure of code, I was able to get the top left block to overflow to the left of the screen without creating a horizontal scroll bar. But for the top right block, trying to overflow the border creates a horizontal scroll bar.

How do I rewrite the code so that overflowing the border does not create a horizontal scroll bar? I don't necessarily want to use `body {  overflow-x: hidden;}`.

I've tried everything I could think of, including tons of suggestions from Claude 3 Opus and GPT4. `width: 100%` only spans to the end of the block and doesn't overflow. I've tried different width calculations like `width: calc(100vw - 25px)` or `width: calc(100vw - 100%)`. Every time the border overflows, it creates the scroll bar.

Comment: you can add some HTML

Comment: why not set the border to be `inset`?

Comment: Thanks. Just tried inset. Still have the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: try using `box-shadow` with `inset`

Comment: Tried it out and still get the scroll bar. Also tried to create a background that functions as the border, but I'm still getting that horizontal scroll bar. The scroll bar seems to extend to about double the width of my page.

Comment: I finally figured it out. My grid is 1050px wide and viewport is 1200. Using this calculation in :after, the border spans to the edge of the screen and no further: "width: calc((100vw - 1050px) / 2 + 23px); left: 100%;"